# Smooth rotating in the direction player is moving towards (in 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I tried to use a script from tutorial that Makes a 3d object rotates smoothly to the direction the object is moving towards and when I tried to use it to my 2d sprite it started to rotate really weird 3D rotating, I am really new to unity so please expect any stupid mistakes and here is the script I used:

```
            float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput).normalized;
            if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
            {
                Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(movementDirection, Vector3.forward);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, 
                rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
```

I tried to replace it with `Vector3.right` but still the same issue, I also tried to replace it with `Vector3.up` but this weird 3D rotation still exist.

Comment: I tried to replace it with `Vector3.right` but still the same issue, I also tried to replace it with `Vector3.up` but this weird 3D rotation still existing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! but can you please explain more clearly how exactly I can use `slerp` for smooth rotation or give me a link for an article that explains that... because I am new to this stuff as I mentioned before.... Thanks!